# How to make a new text file each run of a Program in C?

Tags: c

This is my first post ever so go easy on me if I don't make this post pretty. I have a program in C that calculates wages. I need to have the program make a new text file each time the program is run. I am told to submit 2 .txt files named "csis1.txt" and "csis2.txt", the number which corresponds to each time the program is run. I only know how to make it print one text file, and each time I run the program, it overwrites the same text file. The catch is that my instructor forbids using material from future chapters. It would take so long to write out what I can and can't use, so basically what you see in my code, is using all the different tools I have learned, and which I am allowed to use. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fp;

float noOvertime(float hours, float payrate);
float yesOvertime(float hours, float payrate);
float taxes(float grosspay);

//Main function
int main(void) {

float hours, payrate, grosspay, totalNet, totalTax;

fopen_s(&fp, "csis1.txt", "w");


//Prompts the user for the amount of hours worked
printf("Enter the amount of hours worked: ");
fprintf(fp, "Enter the amount of hours worked: ");
scanf_s("%f", &hours);

if (hours <= 0) {
    printf("You have to of had worked atleast one hour!");
    fprintf(fp, "You have to of had worked atleaset one hour!");
    return 0;
}

//Prompt the user for the payrate
printf("\nEnter the payrate per hour: ");
fprintf(fp, "\nEnter the payrate per hour: ");
scanf_s("%f", &payrate);

//Determine if user worked overtime
if (hours > 0 && hours <= 40) {
    grosspay = noOvertime(hours, payrate);
}
else if (hours > 40) {
    grosspay = yesOvertime(hours, payrate);
}

//Assigning the output of "taxes" function to variable "totalTax"
totalTax = taxes(grosspay);

//Calculating the total net pay and assigning to variable "totalNet"
totalNet = grosspay - totalTax;

//Displaying output to the user
printf("\nGross: $%.2f\nTaxes: $%.2f\nNet: $%.2f\n", grosspay, totalTax, totalNet);
fprintf(fp, "\nGross: $%.2f\nTaxes: $%.2f\nNet: $%.2f\n", grosspay, totalTax, totalNet);

fclose(fp);
return 0;
}

//Calculates the gross pay based on hours worked and payrate
float noOvertime(float hours, float payrate) {

float grosspay = hours * payrate;

return grosspay;
}

//Calculates the gross pay based on hours worked and payrate, with overtime compensation
float yesOvertime(float hours, float payrate) { 

float grosspay = (40 * payrate) + (hours - 40) * 1.5 * payrate;

return grosspay;

}

float taxes(float grosspay) {

float totalTax, tax1, tax2, tax3, net;
float first200 = 200.00;
float next250 = 250.00;

//20 percent tax on first 200 dollars of gross pay
tax1 = first200 * .20;
net = (grosspay - first200) + (first200 - tax1);

//25 percent tax on the next 250 of gross pay
tax2 = next250 * .25;
net = (net - next250) + (next250 - tax2);

//30 percent tax on the remaining gross pay
tax3 = net * .30;
net -= tax3;

totalTax = tax1 + tax2 + tax3;

return totalTax;

}
```

Comment: The beginner's method to solving this problem is to open each possible file for reading `"r"` until the `fopen` fails. Then open that file for writing.

Comment: could you provide an example code? Im sort of confused

Comment: The code `int n=1; char name[100]; sprintf(name, "csis%d.txt", n);` will create a file name that you can use like `fopen_s(&fp, name, "r")`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "csis1.txt" as an argument of `fopen_s()`, just use a custom char array:

```
char file_name[FILE_NAME_SIZE];
fopen_s(&fp, file_name, "w");
```

Comment: Unfortunately I wouldn't be allowed to use arrays, and I don't quite understand how they work yet.

Comment: This is strange, since you are already using files, which requires an understanding of buffers, which in turn, requires knowledge with arrays in order to build strings. Good luck anyways! Could you accept my answer?